# Dont know how to fix A* pathfinding algorithm

Tags: python, a-star

I'm trying the [A* outline from GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/a-search-algorithm/). I followed most of the steps in the grey box until I hit a roadblock on dii and diii. Here is the section of the pathfinding:

```
def pathfind(grid):
    sx, sy = 0, 0
    # find start point and end point cood
    for y in range(len(grid)):
        for x in range(len(grid[y])):
            if grid[y][x] == "S":
                sx = x
                sy = y
            elif grid[y][x] == "E":
                ex = x
                ey = y

    opensq = []
    closedsq = []
    successor = []

    #add starting point to closed
    opensq.append([sx, sy, gcost(sx, sy, sx, sy), hcost(sx, sy, ex, ey)])
    grid[sy][sx] = "O"

    while opensq:
        # find the node with lowest fcost
        q = opensq[0]
        if len(opensq) == 1:
            pass
        else:
            for sq in range(len(opensq)):
                if sq == len(opensq) - 1:
                    pass
                else:
                    if q[2] + q[3] < opensq[sq + 1][2] + opensq[sq + 1][3]:
                        pass
                    elif q[2] + q[3] == opensq[sq + 1][2] + opensq[sq + 1][3]:
                        # if f is same, check hcost
                        if q[3] < opensq[sq + 1][3]:
                            pass
                        elif q[3] == opensq[sq + 1][3]:
                            pass
                        else:
                            q = opensq[sq + 1]
                    else:
                        q = opensq[sq + 1]
        opensq.pop(opensq.index(q))
        # pick successors to q
        successors = []
        successors.append([q[0] + 1, q[1], gcost(q[0] + 1, q[1], sx, sy), hcost(q[0] + 1, q[1], ex, ey)])
        successors.append([q[0] - 1, q[1], gcost(q[0] - 1, q[1], sx, sy), hcost(q[0] - 1, q[1], ex, ey)])
        successors.append([q[0], q[1] + 1, gcost(q[0], q[1] + 1, sx, sy), hcost(q[0], q[1] + 1, ex, ey)])
        successors.append([q[0], q[1] - 1, gcost(q[0], q[1] - 1, sx, sy), hcost(q[0], q[1] - 1, ex, ey)])
        for s in successors:
        #     if successor is the goal, stop search
            if s[0] == ex and s[1] == ey:
                pass
#            if a node with the same position as
#            successor is in the OPEN list which has a
#            lower f than successor, skip this successor
            for sq in opensq:
                if sq[2] + sq[3] < s[2] + s[3]:
                    successors.pop(successors.index(s))
            # if a node with the same position as
            # successor  is in the CLOSED list which has
            # a lower f than successor, skip this successor
            # otherwise, add  the node to the open list
            for sq in closedsq:
                if sq[2] + sq[3] < s[2] + s[3]:
                    successors.pop(successors.index(s))
        for s in successors:
            opensq.append(s)
            grid[s[1]][s[0]] = "O"
        closedsq.append(q)
        grid[q[1]][q[0]] = "C"
```

sx and sy being start point and ex ey being endpoint. I used letters to determine if a node is open or closed or start or end, with their first letter. This error pops up when I run it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Bruh/Desktop/Codes and Scripts/AI/A_Pathfinding/Code.py", line 287, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:/Bruh/Desktop/Codes and Scripts/AI/A_Pathfinding/Code.py", line 274, in main
    pathfind(grid)
  File "D:/Bruh/Desktop/Codes and Scripts/AI/A_Pathfinding/Code.py", line 98, in pathfind
    successors.pop(successors.index(s))
ValueError: [5, 12, 3, 14] is not in list
```

here is the whole script, I used pygame for the visualization but just focus on the pathfind method, it currently kinda works but 1. the closed nodes become open nodes again after each loop for some reason and 2. it will get stuck in a loop if I skip the successor when it faces a wall.
https://pastebin.com/yZfcPkq8

edit: finally finished the code! I'll put it up there, the only problem being that..I dont know hwo to show the path..
https://pastebin.com/EYSxFzpe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs in the following part:

```py
for s in successors:
    if s[0] == ex and s[1] == ey:
        pass

    for sq in opensq:
        if sq[2] + sq[3] < s[2] + s[3]:
            successors.pop(successors.index(s))  # line 1

    for sq in closedsq:
        if sq[2] + sq[3] < s[2] + s[3]:
            successors.pop(successors.index(s))  # line 2
```

On "line 1" and "line 2", `successors.index(s)` can be called after the `s` is already popped in the previous cycle in the `for` loop. Then, the error occurs.

And, more significantly, your code does not perform [A* search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) properly. You should only check "a node with the same position as successor" as you commented on your code. You can try the following code instead of the part mentioned above to fix the problems.

```py
# Iterate over a copy of the list,
# since we are popping elements in the original list.
for s in list(successors):
    if s[0] == ex and s[1] == ey:
        pass

    for sq in opensq + closedsq:
        if sq[0] == s[0] and sq[1] == s[1] and sq[2] + sq[3] <= s[2] + s[3]:
            successors.pop(successors.index(s))
            break
```

And still, the code above is not that neat. You can see that `sq[3] == s[3]` always holds on the `if` statement above since they are `hcost` for the same position. So, you can just compare `sq[2]` to `s[2]`, i.e. `gcost`. (In other words, since `sq[3] == s[3]` holds, you can just do `sq[2] <= s[2]` instead of `sq[2] + sq[3] <= s[2] + s[3]` on the `if` statement above.) I think the A* search algorithm described in the grey box [on GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/a-search-algorithm/) is not that neat.

---

`gcost` is "the movement cost to move from the starting point to a given square on the grid, following the path generated to get there." So you should fix your code:

- Remove `gcost` function
- Fix the lines `gcost` used to

```py
opensq.append([sx, sy, 0, hcost(sx, sy, ex, ey)])
```

```py
successors.append([q[0] + 1, q[1], q[2] + 1, hcost(q[0] + 1, q[1], ex, ey)])
```

```
successors.append([q[0] - 1, q[1], q[2] + 1, hcost(q[0] - 1, q[1], ex, ey)])
```

```
successors.append([q[0], q[1] + 1, q[2] + 1, hcost(q[0], q[1] + 1, ex, ey)])
```

```
successors.append([q[0], q[1] - 1, q[2] + 1, hcost(q[0], q[1] - 1, ex, ey)])
```

---

With the fixes above, it seems your code works. But I think you can still improve your code. One thing we can imporve is separating the node and the `gcost` of the node. Now `opensq` in your code is saving the node coordinate and `gcost` together, and a node can be added to `opensq` more than once if the calculated `gcost`'s are different.

You can also refer [A* pseudocode on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm#Pseudocode). I think it is more neat and clean than [on GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/a-search-algorithm/) which you already referred.

For the **closed** list, you can refer the "**Remark**" after the [pseudocode on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm#Pseudocode):

> **Remark**: In this pseudocode, if a node is reached by one path, removed from openSet, and subsequently reached by a cheaper path, it will be added to openSet again. This is essential to guarantee that the path returned is optimal if the heuristic function is admissible but not consistent. If the heuristic is consistent, when a node is removed from openSet the path to it is guaranteed to be optimal so the test ‘tentative_gScore < gScore[neighbor]’ will always fail if the node is reached again.

The **closed** list [on GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/a-search-algorithm/) is really ***closed*** only if the heuristic function is [**consistent**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_heuristic).

Comment: @bluends Oh, I fixed the code so that the `for` loop iterates over a copy of the list. Since iterating over the original list while popping elements in it leads to not iterating over every elements in it. Please use the fixed code.

Comment: okay lemme try, btw I kinda made it work but it got stuck in a loop when I tried to add walls in between, also apparently the closed nodes became open nodes again after each loop @Gorisanson

Comment: @bluends What loop are you saying? And, you know, the closed nodes in the grey box of [GeeksForGeeks outline](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/a-search-algorithm/) is not **closed**, so I think the outline is not that neat. I think the [outline on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) is much better.

Comment: @bluends I think you can review your code on the basis of the [pseudocode on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm#Pseudocode), then you can fix the error of you code. Or you can post another question for tackling the error. Then, it would be good to attach other parts needed for executing your code (for example, `grid`, `hcost` and `gcost`) on your new post so that answerers can execute your code and give you better answers.

Comment: @bluends Or, can you just edit your question so that it includes other parts needed for executing your code? Please include the version with walls. Then maybe I can help you.

Comment: I edited it, sorry for the inconvenience, I have posted all the problems that I spotted and the whole script, along with some comments

Comment: @bluends I edited my answer, please check it! And note that `<` changed to `<=` in the if statement before `successors.pop(successors.index(s))`.

Comment: @bluends I found that `IndexError: list index out of range` can occur in the `if` statements like `if grid[q[1]][q[0] + 1] != "X":`. So we should check if `q[0] + 1` is in the range of the list first.

Comment: I had a different version of it where it just looks for the successor list
like if s == "X" then skip it

Comment: I decidd to give up on finding guides and just go with my instincts, I did my own version of the A* code and it works! I'll edit the post with the finished code, the only issue is that i dont know how to display the path @Gorisanson

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217340/discussion-between-gorisanson-and-bluends).